# Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c

When I try to run the following C program in my VS code it shows segmentation fault core dumped. How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void read(student);
void display(student);

struct student {
    int roll, result;
    char name[20], depart[20], sex;
    float percent, marks[5];          
};

void main() {        
    struct student s;
    read(s);  
}

void read(struct student std) {
    int c = 0, i;
    printf("enter the roll no:");
    scanf("%d", &std.roll);
    printf("enter the name:\n");
    scanf("%s", std.name);
    printf("enter Sex:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &std.sex);
    printf("Enter the department:\n");
    scanf("%s", std.depart);
    printf("enter the marks in 5 subjects:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", std.marks[i]);      
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: `sex` is not an array.

Comment: unallocated memory i dint understand. and do i have to declare sex separately?

Comment: If you don't understand memory allocation, it will be hard to handle C prog

Comment: should use `scanf("%f", &std.marks[i]);` since you're reading in a float not an integer

Comment: @Sudru You just have to change `sex` to `sex[10]` for example and then change `scanf(" %c",&std.sex);` to `scanf(" %s",std.sex);`. But this is not the only issue in your code.

Comment: You don't have memory allocation problem, and `sex` seems to be used correctly to me (single char read with `%c`). Reading marks is the issue. Also you pass the struct by value, so the read values are lost when `read` returns.

Comment: Why do we need to write & in array but in general we dint use to write it.Can you explain it in short  @user3121023

Comment: When you write `scanf("%s", std.depart)`, the argument decays to a pointer to the first element, so that is equivalent to `scanf("%s", &std.depart[0])`.  IOW, you do use the `&`, but you've used a compiler shortcut to avoid writing it explicitly.

Comment: @hyde It is no issue on its own indeed, but can cause logical programs by the use of the program because he asks implicitly for a word for a gender by`printf("enter Sex:\n");`

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yeah, it'd be best to use `enum` for fixed set of values, instead of just `char`.

Comment: ...but that is least of the only-sometimes-fatal problems in that code.

Comment: do i need to return these value if i want to print these using another function ?

Comment: @Sudru: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the prototypes `void read(student);` and `void display(student);` refer to an undefined type `student`.
- it is problematic to call a function `read` because it conflicts with a similar function in the C library that makes a system call to read files. Either make it `static` or better rename it `read_student`.
- You pass the `student` structure by value to the `read` function: `read` will only modify its argument, not the structure in the `main` function. `read` should receive a pointer to the structure in the caller's scope.
- `main` should be defined as `int main(void)`.
- `scanf()` expects pointers to the destination variables. Passing the variable values as in `scanf("%d", std.marks[i])` will definitely cause undefined behavior very likely resulting in a crash.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    int roll, result;
    char name[20], depart[20], sex;
    float percent, marks[5];          
};

void read_student(struct student *);
void display_student(const struct student *);

int main() {        
    struct student s;
    read_student(&s);
    return 0;
}

void read_student(struct student *std) {
    int i;
    printf("enter the roll no: ");
    scanf("%d", &std->roll);
    printf("enter the name:\n");
    scanf("%19s", std->name);
    printf("enter Sex:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &std->sex);
    printf("Enter the department:\n");
    scanf("%19s", std->depart);
    printf("enter the marks in 5 subjects:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &std->marks[i]);      
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem as discussed in the comments is that when using `scanf` to read a value, you have to pass in a pointer to the variable and in the case of populating an array, you still need to pass in a pointer to each element. And you also need to specify the correct format - `%d` is for reading integers, `%f` is for reading floats.

So the following line of code...

```
scanf("%d", std.marks[i]);
```

...should be

```
scanf("%f", &std.marks[i]);
```

The other problem which you've not yet discovered is you aren't actually populating `s` - you're populating a local copy. To populate `s` you need to pass in a pointer to it like so:

```
read(&s);
```

which means your function would look more like

```
void read(struct student *std) {
     int c=0,i;
     printf("enter the roll no:");
     scanf("%d",&std->roll);
```

and you'd have to use `std->` instead of `std.` to deference the struct elements properly.

As an aside, calling a function `read` is generally not a good idea as there is a C library called `read` - you'd be better off calling it `read_student` to also better indicate what it does.